# couldn't get to detail page for each restaurant from my Restaurant list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

I have a list of restaurants retreived from firestore and and I have to return the detail page of each one  once clicking on the name of the restaurant.
On page ProductGrid I ve returned all my restaurants already stored in firestore then from each name of restaurant I should go to ProductDetail which will contain the details of each restaurant(dynamic routing)
I ve created the routes but no page is returned I can't figure out what is exactly the problem!!
This is the link leading to the productDetail page

**ProductGrid.js**

```
      <h2> <Link to={`ecom-product-detail/${data.id}`}>{data.data.name_restaurant}</Link> </h2><<
```

**ProductDetail.js**

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { firestore } from "../../../../../fire";

function ProductDetail(){

   const {productId}= useParams();
   const thisProduct = firestore.collection("Restaurants").doc().get.find((prod) => prod.id === productId);

return(

  
      <div className="col-12">
      <div className="card">
            <h1>{thisProduct.name_restaurant}</h1>
            <p> Price:${thisProduct.Currency}</p>
            <p> {thisProduct.email}          </p>
      </div>
      </div>
   
      
    ) ; }
    export default ProductDetail;
```

**Route.js**

```
    const Routes = () => {
    const routes = [
      { url: "ecom-product-detail/:productId", component: ProductDetail },
      ];
      return (
      <Fragment>
         <Switch>
            {routes.map((data, i) => (
               <Route
                  key={i}
                  exact
                  path={`/${data.url}`}
                  component={data.component}
               />
            ))}
         </Switch>

         {/* <Footer /> */}
      </Fragment>
   );
};

export default Routes;
```

**This is my Restaurants List retreived from firestore**
[image]

**This the page rendered when I click on the name of the restaurant**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `thisProduct` inside a `useEffect` hook and bind the result to a `useState` hook.

Something like this :

```
const {productId}= useParams();
const [thisProduct, setThisProduct] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
const productDetails = firestore.collection("Restaurants").doc().get.find((prod) => prod.id === productId);
   setThisProduct(productDetails);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for interacting! But this hasn't changed anything the same page is reloaded even when I only want to return a text "hello world" nothing was returned !! I think the problem is the routing from ProductGrid this is the link I've written should I change anything here ??  ` <Link to={`ecom-product-detail/${data.data.id}`}>{data.data.name_restaurant}</Link>`

Comment: If you have a Github repo or Stack Blitz project i can help.